# Can't access website if I add "www" in prefix

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have successfully hosted the website `http://etutionhub.com` which is working fine so far but the issue is that I cannot access it if I add prefix (www) before the url.

What could be the issue here? I am sure my domain dns setting are fine which are attached below.

[image: domain dns settings]

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure portal, you only set up the `etutionhub.com` host name. You also need to explicitly add `www.etutionhub.com` in there and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The `www` prefix is just part of domain name. If you expect to work the `www.domain` address, you need to specify it as another address.